# Why there are "NA"s in the name of numeric results of igraph get.subisomorphism

Tags: r, numeric, igraph, isomorphism

I'm doing the subgraph isomorphism using **igraph** library in **R**.

I have two graphs `p1` and `p2`:

```
p1 =graph.formula("1"--+"2")
V(p1)$color = c(1,2)
E(p1)$color = c(2)

p2 =graph.formula("a"--+"b"--+"c")
V(p2)$color=c(1,1, 2)
E(p2)$color=c(2,2)
```

I got the result when applying **graph.subisomorphic**:

```
result1 = graph.subisomorphic.vf2(p2,p1)

result1
$iso [1] TRUE
$map12 [1] 0 1 2
$map21 [1] 2 3
```

I can understand this result which contains two mappings.

However, I want to get all the subisomorphisms, so I applied another function called graph.get.subisomorphism. 
According to R documentation, the result is a list of named numeric vectors:

"graph.get.subisomorphisms.vf2 returns a list of numeric vectors, each numeric vector is an isomorphic mapping from graph2 to a subgraph of graph1."

```
> result2 = graph.get.subisomorphisms.vf2(p2,p1)

result2

[[1]]   
2 < NA >   
2    3
```

Could anyone help me explain the result? Why there is a `< NA >` as the name of the numeric vector?

Comment: The name is wrong, just ignore the names of the vector.